# Multiple ArcMap Instances

Tags: arcgis-desktop, performance

Is ArcGIS designed in a way that it is possible to open and work in multiple ArcMap instances/documents?

I am wondering, when I have some time-consuming operations running in the ArcMap document 1, but want to work in the meantime on another project where I need to test my arcpy code, which I would like to do in ArcMap document 2, if the operations in ArcMap document 2 influence the performance/duration of the operations in ArcMap document 1?

Comment: Someone more knowledgable in the topic can probably create an informative answer, but I personally almost always have multiple instances of Arcmap running simultaneously. Each Arcmap instance can only use one core (?), so shouldn't really be a problem to run multiple parallell processes without affecting each other (at least until #Arcmap processes >= #cores).

Comment: I didn't know that about the cores, but it totally makes sense. I just wanted to be sure that the first document is not influenced negatively by the second one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My workstation is getting a bit old, but it has 8 cores and 12 GB RAM running Windows 7.  I typically have multiple instances of ArcMap open at the same time and don't worry about the interaction.  But there are times when one ArcMap will slow other things down. Using DDP or Arcpy to export a series of maps with imagery (especially from an outside server), the write process can slow everything else down.  Complex overlays can also hog resources. Multiple instances writing to pdf at the same time may as well perhaps because they need to use the same dlls.  Windows has its limits.

Comment: If you are interested in there is an answer from esri in the following link(a bit old though): http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31903 . But even if you set the processing environment to multiple cores it just don´t uses them, or at least many tools don´t.

Comment: Slightly off topic but annoyingly, ArcGIS Pro only allows one instance of the application to run.

Comment: That does indeed sound annoying. Why would they do that? I'm just about to start trying out ArcGIS Pro, but if I can't have more than one window open at any time I might not even bother...

Comment: @Matte I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A year ago I "Exported" multiple maps from multiple instances at 600dpi and it worked fine (eg each map processed over 2 hours to PDF). This year I do the same thing for the same type of map document and complexity, although I do increase resolution to 1440dpi and while the primary dataframe printed fine, the other dataframes on the same map did not. The case was the same for all maps, where 4/5 dataframes did not export their data.  As for why I am not sure. The only difference on the machine (i7-4790k) itself last year had 32gb ram and this year 16gb.  Also new video card gtx970.72

As for working, if you are exporting from another instance and the active instance also has a complex map (ie lots of labels from many layers) then the constant refreshing of the layout view as it updates can be slow and painful. 
This is slowed even more with a 2nd instance that is also exporting to pdf.

There is generally no issue with multiple instances being open and working on them separately. This works well when one is geoprocessing and one is editing etc.

There may be conflict issues when working with Personal or File geodatabases shared between one or more map documents.  There may also be issues with working on x64 machines doing "background processing" while working with Personal/MS Access geodatabases. On average though record locking issues are most common with file geodatabases that generally hamper productivity with random read-write conflicts.

There are probably many more things that could be considered that may affect working with multiple Arc instances.